# Referencing data package current version in guest executable

Tags: java, azure-service-fabric, lightstreamer

I'm deploying [Lightstreamer Moderato](http://www.lightstreamer.com/ls-features) *(free for production use)* as a stateless guest executable in Service Fabric.

I extracted Java in a `jdk` folder and Lightstreamer to a `ls` folder in a `CodePackage` called `lib`. Everything is working perfectly. The maintenance problem is that the config package version has to be specified in the `ExeHost` `Arguments` element:

`ServiceManifest.xml`:

```
  <CodePackage Name="lib" Version="1.2.3">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>jdk\bin\java.exe</Program>
        <Arguments>-server -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000 -Dcom.lightstreamer.kernel_lib_path=".\ls\lightstreamer.jar" -Dcom.lightstreamer.internal_lib_path=".\ls\ls-monitor.jar";".\ls\core\*" -Dcom.lightstreamer.logging_lib_path=".\ls\ls-logging-utilities.jar";".\ls\log\*" -cp ".\ls\ls-bootstrap.jar";".\ls\ls-adapter-interface.jar" com.lightstreamer.LS "..\Lightstreamer-Main.conf.2.0\lightstreamer_conf.xml"</Arguments>
    <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
        <ConsoleRedirection FileRetentionCount="5" FileMaxSizeInKb="2048"/>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
  </CodePackage>

  <ConfigPackage Name="conf" Version="2.0" />
```

How can a Service Fabric guest executable `ServiceManifest.xml` reference the correct `ConfigPackage` deployment in the command-line arguments?

Answer (score 2):

Use `SetupEntryPoint` to find the latest cfg version folder, create a symlink,  and change the command-line arguments to use the symlink instead of the versioned cfg package path.